# Plot "large" raster with leaflet in R

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny, mapview

I have a geotiff that is around 26MB on my hard drive. I would like to use `leaflet` to plot it within a shiny application.
However, it just doesn't load. When I use `mapview` just to plot it locally it also takes some seconds, but eventually it will be plotted. To my knowledge it's better to use `leaflet` in a shiny-app. So I don't know exactly what to do now.

Here is some code, that produces a raster of more or less similar size

```r
r = raster()
res(r) = 0.1
r[] = runif(ncell(r)) 

# plot it with mapview
mapview::mapview(r)

# plot it with leaflet
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addRasterImage(r)
```

Comment: Still experimental, but `leafem::addGeotiff` could be a solution here. It expects a file path to the geotiff so doesn't need to be loaded into the R session first. If you want to load it into R first, then `leafem::addGeoRaster` is the function to use. See [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/leafem/issues/25) for a bit of backround around these functions. Note: they are currently in the github version only, so `remotes::install_github("r-spatial/leafem")` to get them.

Comment: thank you very much! I'll give this a try later today:) And also thanks a lot for the amazing packages that I use almost daily